# Problema con el responsive al agregar ReCaptcha V2

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Mi problema es el el login de mi web, que sin agregar el widget de recaptcha se ve así (solo pasa en dispositivos moviles el problema):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y cuando agrego el recaptcha se ve así:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué debo modificar? **QUE NO SEA CAMBIAR A `COMPACT` DENTRO DEL DIV G-RECAPTCHA PORQUE ES VISUALMENTE FEO.** Estoy usando un framework basado en Bootstrap 5.

**Mi código:**

```
<!--begin::Main-->
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-root">
      <!--begin::Authentication - Sign-in -->
      <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-column-fluid bgi-position-y-bottom position-x-center bgi-no-repeat bgi-size-contain bgi-attachment-fixed" style="background-size1: 100% 50%; background-image: url(assets/media/misc/outdoor.png)">
        <!--begin::Content-->
        <div class="d-flex flex-center flex-column flex-column-fluid p-10 pb-lg-20">
          <!--begin::Logo-->
          <a href="index.html" class="mb-12">
            <img alt="Logo" src="assets/media/logos/logo-2.svg" class="h-45px" />
          </a>
          <!--end::Logo-->
          <!--begin::Wrapper-->
          <div class="w-lg-500px bg-white rounded shadow-sm p-10 p-lg-15 mx-auto">
            <!--begin::Form-->
            <form class="form w-100" novalidate="novalidate" id="kt_sign_in_form" action="" method="POST">
              <!--begin::Heading-->
              <div class="text-center mb-10">
                <!--begin::Title-->
                <h1 class="text-dark mb-3">Welcome to <?php echo($settings->getName()) ?></h1>
                <!--end::Title-->
                <!--begin::Link-->
                <div class="text-gray-400 fw-bold fs-4">New Here?
                <a href="register" class="link-primary fw-bolder">Create an Account</a></div>
                <!--end::Link-->
              </div>
              <!--begin::Heading-->
              <!--begin::Input group-->
              <div class="fv-row mb-10">
                <?php echo($error); ?>
                <!--begin::Label-->
                <label class="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder text-dark">Email</label>
                <!--end::Label-->
                <!--begin::Input-->
                <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" type="text" name="aa" id="aa" required="" autofocus=""/>
                <!--end::Input-->
              </div>
              <!--end::Input group-->
              <!--begin::Input group-->
              <div class="fv-row mb-5">
                <!--begin::Wrapper-->
                <div class="d-flex flex-stack mb-2">
                  <!--begin::Label-->
                  <label class="form-label fw-bolder text-dark fs-6 mb-0">Password</label>
                  <!--end::Label-->
                </div>
                <!--end::Wrapper-->
                <!--begin::Input-->
                <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" type="password" name="ss" id="ss" required="" />
                <!--end::Input-->
              </div>
              <!--end::Input group-->
              <!--begin::Actions-->
              <div class="text-center">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $CAPTCHA_KEY; ?>"></div>
</div>
              <div class="text-center">
                <!--begin::Submit button-->
                <button type="submit" id="kt_button_1" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary w-100 mb-5">
                  <span class="indicator-label">Continue</span>
                  <span class="indicator-progress">Please wait...
                  <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle ms-2"></span></span>
                </button>
                <!--end::Submit button-->
              </div>
              <!--end::Actions-->
            </form>
            <!--end::Form-->
          </div>
          <!--end::Wrapper-->
        </div>
        <!--end::Content-->
        <!--begin::Footer-->
        <div class="d-flex flex-center flex-column-auto p-10">
          <!--begin::Links-->
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center fw-bold fs-6">
            <a href="https://keenthemes.com/faqs" class="text-muted text-hover-primary px-2">About</a>
            <a href="mailto:support@keenthemes.com" class="text-muted text-hover-primary px-2">Contact</a>
            <a href="https://1.envato.market/EA4JP" class="text-muted text-hover-primary px-2">Contact Us</a>
          </div>
          <!--end::Links-->
        </div>
        <!--end::Footer-->
      </div>
      <!--end::Authentication - Sign-in-->
    </div>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme porque no encuentro manera de arreglarlo.
Probé modificando `<div class="w-lg-500px bg-white rounded shadow-sm p-10 p-lg-15 mx-auto">` quitando el `mx-auto` y pasando de `p-10` a `p-5` pero visualmente queda horrible.

También probé con algunos códigos CSS que encontré en internet para hacer responsive el widget pero tampoco me funcionó.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar poner con CSS al captcha

```
.captcha{max-width: 100%;}
```

o 90% o 95% de cauerdo a tu gusto

Comment: acabo de intentar y no funcionó :(

Comment: Bueno la clase no es .captcha sino .g-recaptcha